# Changing the figure legend to indicate the line type... (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the formula below:

```
ggplot(Errortrialsmodifyoriginal, aes(x = Target, y = Absolutefirststoperror, color = as.character(Type), shape = as.character(Type))) +
 geom_point(shape=16)+
 geom_point(data=Errortrialoriginal,shape=19,size = 4,mapping=aes(x=Target, y=Absolutefirststoperror)) +
 geom_line(data=Errortrialoriginal,aes(group=Type,linetype=Type),size=2,) +
 scale_color_manual(name = "Condition", values = c("red","green","blue","red","green","blue")) +
 scale_linetype_manual(name = "Condition",values = c("dashed","dashed","dashed","solid","solid","solid")) +
 geom_errorbar(data=Errortrialoriginal,mapping=aes(x=Target, ymin=Absolutefirststoperror-SE,ymax=Absolutefirststoperror+SE),size=0.5) +
 theme_bw() + guides(color = guide_legend("Condition"), shape = guide_legend("Condition"), linetype = guide_legend("Condition")) +
 labs(x = "Target distance (vm)", y = "Absolute error in stop location (vm)") +
 theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=14),title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"), axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Which produces the graph:

[image]

How can I change my command to ensure that the dashed and solid lines are shown in the figure legend; because at the moment, the figure legend suggests that all the lines are solid, even though they are not?

I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Hi Caledonian, your question was migrated to Stack Overflow. Can you provide `Errortrialsmodifyoriginal` with `dput(Errortrialsmodifyoriginal)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my opinion, the legend is correctly displayed but you can't see it because you have big points front of the linetype. You should increase the legend box to see it.

Here an example with this dummy example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = dose, y = length, color = supp, linetype = supp))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size = 4)
```

[image]

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = dose, y = length, color = supp, linetype = supp))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"))
```

[image]

So, with your code, you can do something like that:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Errortrialsmodifyoriginal, 
       aes(x = Target, 
           y = Absolutefirststoperror, 
           color = Type)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line(data=Errortrialoriginal,
            aes(group=Type,
                linetype=Type)) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Condition", values = rep(c("red","green","blue"),2)) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Condition",values = rep(c("dashed","solid"),each =3)) + 
  geom_errorbar(data=Errortrialoriginal,
                mapping=aes(x=Target, 
                            ymin=Absolutefirststoperror-SE,
                            ymax=Absolutefirststoperror+SE),size=0.5) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(color = guide_legend("Condition"), shape = guide_legend("Condition"), linetype = guide_legend("Condition")) + 
  labs(x = "Target distance (vm)", y = "Absolute error in stop location (vm)") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=14),
        title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"))
```

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please consider providing a reproducible example of your dataset (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: #dc37 thanks that worked! Could you clarify exactly what the "line" means in the last part of the command? Ah, I gather it means the unit of spacing, so 3, "cm" would be 3cm apart for each line in the figure legend?